# Websocket closing for no reason in Redis Pub/Sub callback

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, redis, publish-subscribe, stackexchange.redis

Hello i have an `ASP NET Core Middleware` that uses `Websockets` and `Redis Pub/Sub`.
A user connects with a websocket to the server and:

- incoming `websocket` messages get published in a Redis channel via `Pub/Sub`
- incoming `Redis` channel messages get written on the `websocket` back to the client.

**Problem**

Now whenever the user disconnects and reconnects ,the `Redis` message handler method throws exception with the socket state being `Closed (Normal closure)`.

The weird part is that the reconnected client has its websocket in `Open` state up until the message is published to Redis.Then the code throws on the Redis callback thread/task with the socket being in `Closed` state.

Therefore i conclude that the new webocket is closed by the server and not the client !

**How to reproduce**

```
-user connects
-user sends messages ( and gets them back via redis callback)
-user disconnects
-user reconnects
   - code goes well until the user publishes the first message to redis at which point , the redis callback throws exception:
```

> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException: 'The remote party closed the
> WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake.'
>
> Inner Exception:  ObjectDisposedException: Cannot write to the
> response body, the response has completed. Object name:
> 'HttpResponseStream'.

**Startup**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime) {
            
             //connecting to redis
            ConnectionMultiplexer connectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379");
            app.UseWebSockets();
            app.Use(async (con,req) => {

                if (!con.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest) {
                    await req();
                }

                //accepting ws
                WebSocket socket = await con.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();

               
                ISubscriber subscriber = connectionMultiplexer.GetSubscriber();

                //subscribing to redis channel 
                await subscriber.SubscribeAsync("mychannel",
                      async(chan,val) => await socket.SendAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(val),  
                                                     System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageType.Text,
                                                     true,
                                                     CancellationToken.None) //throws right here when user reconnects and publishes from the main Task the first message to redis
                ,CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
                var database = connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                
                //loop for publishing client ws messages to redis channel
                while (true) {
                    WebSocketReceiveResult result=await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
                    if (result.MessageType == System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageType.Close) {
                        return;
                    }
                    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer[0..result.Count]);
                    
                    await database.PublishAsync("mychannel", data);
                }
            });
}
```

**P.S**
I am 100% sure the client does not close the socket.I have tried using Google [Simple Web Socket Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo?hl=en) and also a javascript one.

**Wild Guess**
I was thinking the `Redis` message handler provided by the `ISubscriber`  somehow closures an old socket (whose session has ended) and re-uses it for a new client.Thus it would explain why the socket used by the redis callback is in `Closed` state.

Comment: Doc indicates that `WebSocket` should be used with `using` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I have just tested it enclosing in a `using` to no avail.